# Op-amp gain not working as expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, shunt

I'm trying to amplify a really small (1.3 mV) voltage from a sense resistor. I am using the following schematic:

[image]

My load is an LED and resistor. For R2, I'm using a 470 kΩ resistor. For R1, I'm using a 470 Ω resistor. The op-amp I am using is the [LM358P](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/LM358).

I expected the gain to be 1000 with an output voltage of 1.3 V, but I am getting an output voltage of 3.8 V. What am I missing here?

Comment: A quick look says that LM358's input offset voltage is 2mV, that's already almost double from what you're trying to measure...

Comment: You could read something as this https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa215a/sboa215a.pdf?ts=1659970435081&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FCIRCUIT060029 and https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa353a/sbaa353a.pdf?ts=1659970555415&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FCIRCUIT060029

Comment: @Unimportant At least it ain't a 741! 358 is the current default.

Comment: You need a better opamp. There are specialized ones for the very purpose is current sense.

Comment: For future analog designs, you should consider using a SPICE simulator as much as possible, such as LTSpice (free software). This will answer a lot of your future questions

Comment: What are the supplies for this op-amp?

Comment: What is the output when no current is flowing through Rsense? You probably just need to add offset (zero) adjustment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggest you replace the LM358 with a 'zero drift' op-amp such as [this](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncs21871-d.pdf) one. It has 45uV maximum input offset voltage compared to several mV for the LM358/LM324.

With your gain of 1000, the output offset is thus +/-45mV compared to +/-2V for the LM358, about 50:1 improvement. The drift with temperature is also much lower, at least by 10:1, so it's much better than attempting to trim out the + or - offset voltage.

With such a low value of shunt you also need to take special care to make Kelvin connections to the resistor, preferably use a 4-terminal resistor designed for this kind of application. Even a short bit of copper trace in the wrong place can greatly harm the span accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few reasons why that isn't a great circuit.  The first, assuming that all of your resistors are perfectly matching, is that op-amps have an inherent input offset voltage. that will get amplified along with everything else.  A strong second is that resistor mismatch will do unpleasant things.

There are a variety of ways to fix this.  One is to simply post-calibrate your circuit, and come up with an equation for the variable of interest with respect to output voltage.

Another is to use an auto-zeroing instrumentation amp, as described in https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-067.pdf.

Autozeroing amps in some ways can be considered sampling devices, so you need to be careful about spreading clock noise throughout your project, as well as aliasing.

Also, a gain of 1,000 might do bad things to your frequency response.  You should consider daisychaining gain stages

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of information, I tried to reproduce the configuration in simulation.

The result obtained is not surprising, the choice of the "good" components remains to be made.

Voltages supply Vc: 10/-10 or 15/-15 V.
R2 and R7 vary in the "precision" of the resistors (450 kOhm to 490 kOhm).
Voltages output are around 3.8 -> 4.0 V,  for a sensed current of 2 A.

[image]

Now, adjusting offset, as pointed out by @PStechPaul ...

[image]

With a "zoom in the circled area ...

With "offset", well centered, it could be ok ...

[image]

But what is going on if I vary now temperature?

[image]

Not "bad" ... To be "checked" ...